# Only some modules in .gitmodules are cloned and branch config isn't used

Tags: git

My `.gitmodules` file looks like this:

```
[submodule "server"]
    path = server
    url = https://github.com/companyName/app-name-server
    branch = master
[submodule "client"]
    path = client
    url = https://github.com/companyName/app-name-client
    branch = master
[submodule "deploy-instructions"]
    path = deploy-instructions
    url = https://github.com/companyName/app-name-deploy-instructions
    branch = master
[submodule "shared"]
    path = shared
    url = https://github.com/companyName/app-name-shared
    branch = master
```

When I clone the repo and run `git submodule update --init --recursive`, the `server` and `client` submodules get pulled but `deploy-instruction` and `shared` don't. Also both `server` and `client` aren't on the master branch.

What is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also both server and client aren't on the master branch.

The submodule update will checkout those submodules to their gitlink recorded SHA1 in the index of the parent repo, irrespective of the branch.
If you want them to pull the master branch and update to its HEAD, you need:

```
git submodule update --remote
```

> deploy-instruction and shared don't.

Check the result of `git ls-files --stage | grep 160000`: if you don't see those two folders, that means their gitlink has been overwritten by an actual (non-submodule) folder of the same name.